# I want to record the time when I click on the link and end the record from when I click on the other link on the other page

Tags: javascript, php

First link :

```
<td style="text-align: center;>
  <font size="1">
    <a href="Evaluation_Form.php?id=<?php echo $row_member['id']; ?>" target="_blank">Evaluate</a>
  </font>
 </td>
```

Second link / button :

```
<input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: The first link can save the time in a session variable, and when you submit the second form it can read the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

for time the most easier way is to use linux TIMESTAMP who is a integer in seconds so easier to manage and manipulate than other date using mathematical base 60 and 12/24.
In SQL you've CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() OR NOW() and in JavaScript you can use the Date object such
`var timestamp=new Date().getTime();`
So do it twice and substract the 2nd time to the 1st one and you'll had time duration(or if database need it keep the 2 timestamps registred).

edit: you can obtain PHP timestamp with function time(), mind it's time of server and not local time of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backend API in PHP to save time spent in page like below, it did not depend on what page, only calculate base on ready page and unload page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var startPage = new Date();

  $(window).unload(function() {
      var leavePage = new Date();
      var page = (location.pathname+location.search).substr(1);
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/api/stayonpage",
            data: {'timeOnPage': leavePage - startPage, 'page' : page },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , doesn't matter where this code put it right ?

Comment: You put to your page that want to record or move to a global js file

Comment: @MohammedHassis Have you recorded the time yet?